# How to know if 2 ethernet ports of the same modem are separated?

Tags: networking, ethernet, ip-address, modem

I have a Digi TransPort WR family of 3G/4G cellular routers with 2 ethernet ports, digi told me that the ethernet ports are separated but i want to know if they are not in the same network it's a matter of security just to be sure that you can't access lan0 from lan1.

Any idea to test ? especially if its possible by AT commands through SSH connexion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume by 'connected' you mean it is basically a switch? Connect a different client to each end, give the clients IPs from the same subnet, check if you can ping client B from client A.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, does it have the same impact if the subnet of the clients isn't the same ? (regarding the ports connexion)

Comment: It has to be the same if you want to test whether it acts as a switch.

Comment: It's not really a switch but a modem with a private address in lan1 and a public address in lan0 and you should not be able to access the client of one of them from the other port (you can't access client in the lan0 from a client in lan1), i got what you are saying about and i thank you i'll test this as soon as i get the modem. thanks